# IE7 appends but doesn't load <script> when injected

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

I have a JS that lives before closing `</body>` tag that contains a method that injects another `<script>` element to load a JS file if a certain action is performed.

The code snippet for the append looks something like this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');

script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
script.setAttribute('src', 'http://path/to/script.js');

document.body.appendChild(script);
```

That code works fine on all browsers except for IE7.  On IE7, it successfully appends the script into the DOM, but does not load it.

Another thing that I'd like to point out is that I have also tried to append that script to `<head>` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Don't use `setAttribute` to set properties of `DOMElements`, IE might choke on that; use native properties instead. E.g., use `script.type = 'text/javascript';`. Moreover, what's the current document mode?

Comment: Define "all browsers" (mainly does it includes ie6, 8 and 9?)

Comment: All browsers = IE > 7, FF, Chrome, Safari

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: the JS console tells me that type is not a function.

Comment: @Koes: that's correct, it's not a function, you shouldn't run it like a function, but set its value, like I showed you.

Comment: that did not fix the issue.  i use <!doctype html> for the document mode.

Comment: How can you tell it's not loaded? Did you check for syntax error?

Comment: Erm ... because it doesn't do what it's supposed to do, like the script does on IE8, IE9, FF, Safari, Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding your `script` element to the `body` element (which is not closed when you try to do that just *before* the closing `</body>` tag), try to add your script to the `head`. Moreover, don't use `setAttribute`, but set properties of the new `DOMElement` directly:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://path/to/script.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the script after the DOM has finished loading? I know IE6 has problems with modifying the DOM before it has been loaded (Will fatal with: Can not load this page).

Either use `window.onload` or just put the script in a javascript file that you include in the header.

Also, in case the JavaScript resource is not actually a JavaScript file but some script that generates a JavaScript file make sure you're sending the JavaScript content header.

Comment: That's how it's currently set up.  The parent script is placed before the closing body tag and it's also a self executing script.

Comment: @Koes: No, at the end of the `body` element ≠ within `window.onload`: if the `body` element is not closed, you shouldn't modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried appending the script tag and then setting the source? I know IE7 requires this order when appending style tags so it might be worth a shot!